# Do compilers `constexpr` everything?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, constexpr

Do compilers try to `constexpr`<sup>1</sup> *everything*? Not just functions/variables/things explicitly marked `constexpr` by the programmer? Before someone comments

> yeah duh, that's what optimization is

A better phrasing of this question might be: at max optimization does the compiler go until it cannot `constexpr` anything else? Or is there some limitation practical or otherwise that means it can only `constexpr` some subset of the program?

<sup><sup>1</sup> read: evaluate/solve at compile-time</sup>

Comment: 1. It's compiler-dependant. 2. Typically compilers do not try too hard in this regard. Any simple expression will most likely be computed. Functions however (most likely) will not, unless they are inlined. 3. Compilers use heuristics for anything and everything. Including whether to try inlining functions. So the question becomes "Is some heuristic met?".

Comment: Compilers don't "`constexpr`" functions just because you declare them such. Compilers, even with optimization settings, may well not evaluate such functions at compile time unless they are used in a place that is syntactically *required* to have compile-time evaluation.

Comment: Starting reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation may give you some answers...

Comment: @NicolBolas I think you are reading the question a bit too pedantically. `constexpr` here is meant not in the literal -- as defined by the C++ standard -- sense (hence the footnote), but as a proxy term for the compiler evaluating the programmers *logic* rather than abstracting straight to low-level things like memory etc. I use the term because it is colloquially known for this.

Comment: @JacobFaib "*as a proxy term for the compiler evaluating the programmers logic rather than abstracting straight to low-level things like memory etc*" I don't know what you mean by that. I understand your question to be referring to evaluating code at compile-time. My point is that even declaring a function as `constexpr` does not *guarantee* compile-time evaluation.

Comment: *I don't know what you mean by that*. "Normal" optimization is done after the code has been transformed from the AST into compiler-specific IR, usually some form of memory-abstracted IR such as SSA. `constexpr` -- read: compile-time solve operations -- from what I understand walk the AST (or something close to it) itself, and hence can be thought of as *logically* walking the code since it works with something close to the source language semantics. Sources: https://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2019-July/062799.html https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ConstantInterpreter.html

Comment: cont. Either way, I think we are arguing past each other :(. @Jean-BaptisteYunès link is pretty close to what my question was getting at.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler must do everything the language requires.

On top of that the compiler can do whatever it likes as long as the result is *as if* it didn't do anything extra.

So it is totally up to the compiler what it does and there are lots of non-optimizing or barely optimizing compilers out there. A good optimizing compiler will go a long way trying to evaluate as much as possible at compile time but generally only up to some internal limit. Otherwise it might never finish. The compiler would have to solve the halting problem otherwise.

That said it's always fun to have some pages of c++ code that do lots of computations and have the compiler produce a binary that contains just `puts("The answer is 42.\n");`.